# Dynamically writing and evaluating a <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I want to dynamically write (and have evaluated) a script I write to a tag.  Why won't this code work?

```
<html>
<head>

<script id="cojs">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('cojs').innerHTML = 'alert("hey");';
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May i ask Why? can't you use `eval`?

Comment: ...why do you want to do that anyway? why can't you just do the alert("hey"); (or other code) right where it's at? Why the need to somehow place (and execute) it somewhere else? It's not going to somehow make it execute before other stuff or anything..

Comment: Scrum: I'm open to using eval() or whatever works to dynamically run js.  Crayon: This is a simple example.  I have to run javascript in response to an ajax response in my actual code.

Comment: Use a callback function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well script tags are evaluated when they are parsed. So since the section above is not parsed anymore after you alter it, it doesn't work.

If your usecase allows it try the eval function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    eval('alert("hey");');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script to be interpreted you need to add it to the document.
Some browsers don't use innerHTML for scripts, but all will set a script's text property.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title> title</title>

<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        who= document.createElement('script');
        who.text= 'alert("hey");';
        head.appendChild(who);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```